# Get JSON file from mongodump

Tags: json, mongodb, export, mongodump, mongoexport

I'm trying to export one of my mongo collections using this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongodump" -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

I have a BSON file with my db collection but i want it in a JSON file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/):

> `mongodump` is a utility for creating a binary export of the contents of a database
>
> **--out , -o**
>
> Specifies the directory where mongodump will write BSON files for the dumped databases

So `mongodump` outputs BSON.

If you want to output JSON then you have to use `mongoexport`. From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/):

> `mongoexport` is a utility that produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongoexport" -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -db <database name> --collection <collection name> --out mongo_output.json
```